# Inequality of norm of linear functionals on $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\varphi \in B(H)^*$, that is, $\varphi :B(H) \to \mathbb C$ be a bounded linear functional. Let $u \in B(H)$ be a partial isometry. Let us define $\varphi_u : B(H) \to \mathbb C$ by the assignment:
$$\varphi_u(a)=\varphi(au^*),~~\forall~a \in B(H),$$
where $u^*$ is the adjoint of $u$ in $B(H)$. Now I want to prove that $\|\varphi_u\| \le \|\varphi\|$.
**My attempt:** Now notice that,
$$\|\varphi_u\|=\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \vert \varphi_u(x)\vert =\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \vert \varphi(xu^*)\vert.$$
I am unable to proceed from here. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: If $u\neq 0$ is a partial isometry then $\|u^*\|=1.$

Comment: Just use boundedness of $\phi$, and sub-multiplicativity of the norm on $B(H)$.